# Adding color/flavor during and after fermentation?

Tags: recipe, primary, porter

After a week of fermentation I'm realizing I missed my mark on color and flavor:

**What I've got:**
A great brown porter

**What I want:**
A more robust porter

I'm wondering if I steep some *Midnight Wheat* or *Blackprinz* (what I have on hand) and add it to the end of primary if it would get me closer to the results I'm looking for?

---

**Details:**
10 gal. split batch, WLP005 & WLP001 (64 deg. 2.5 days, 68 deg. 4 days)

O.G 1.072

(WLP005 @ 1.012)(WLP001 @ 1.020)...current(11/2/13)

16 lbs. pale 2 row

1  lbs. C 40L

1  lbs. C 80L

1  lbs. chocolate

.5 lbs. blackprinz

---

This is right in between a brown and a porter, leaning brown, and I want so bad for it to be a great robust porter! help!

Comment: Please add a link to the malt types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to steep grains to make more wort, be sure to boil it to kill spoilage organisms and also to remove the oxygen.

You could try steeping another 0.5lb of the blackprinz and 1lb of the black wheat might give more of the stronger roastiness you'd expect in a robust porter, but since both of these malts is huskless, you're not going to get some of the acrid dry bitterness that is typically found in robust porters.

The [malt analysis sheet](http://www.brewingwithbriess.com/Assets/PDFs/Briess_PISB_BlackprinzMalt.pdf) for blackprinz says that 2-5% gives color with subtle, smooth flavor. and 5-10% gives a mild roastiness. You currently have ca. 5%, so it's not surprising the roasted flavor isn't as strong as you would like. 10% may be better, but hard to say if it will be enough for you - I've not tasted that malt.

If you can get some black malt, carafa III (regular, not dehusked), or roasted barley, 1/4lb of that will help add the stronger roasted bitterness.

Comment: The one thing I'd add is don't wait til the end of primary to add it.  You need active fermentation happening to make sure tit's fully fermented.

Comment: Absolutely - I had this in my head but forgot to mention it!